# Get id of a div that has a specific class

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, class

This is a Fiddle of my site page: https://jsfiddle.net/e1bhwvj8/1/

I want to clear the information of the form on the currently active tab via a button press.

The tabs each have a unique id, as do their forms, but only the currently active one will have the "active" class assigned to it.

```
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div id="general" class="tab active">
                    <form id="generalForm">
                      <div id="tabTableContainer">
                        <table style="width:60%">
                          <tr>
```

I'm wondering how I can detect which div has the "active" class and then get the div id, so I can then know which form to reset.

Comment: are you using jquery

Comment: u can try `$('.active').attr('id')` to get the id of the `active` class if you're using jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [this updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e1bhwvj8/3/).

So I have changed your function `resetTab` to this:

```
function resetTab() {
    jQuery(".tabs div.active form")[0].reset();
}
```

The selector finds the `div` with class `active` among the other tabs inside the `.tabs` div. Then inside the active tab(div) it finds the `form`. The `[0]` means that it is using the first element of the returned collection(you may want to put an `if` in case of no form is found) and apply [`reset()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset) to it.

I think you can try loop through `jQuery(".tabs form")` and apply `reset()` to all to perform a *clearAll* function, but I didn't tried it.

<sup>Note: I have changed your fiddle script setting to *"wrap in < head >"*  instead of *"onLoad"* or your code would never work.</sup>

Comment: Wonderful thanks :) I also have nested tabs, I'm new to jQuery, I assume I can do a simply if checking which major tab is active, then have this reset function for the active sub tab?

Comment: @Tom the question is: how many tabs has the `.active` class? Only the nested one, or the parent has it too ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jQuery you can select the div element then select one that has the active class as:

```
var thisID = $('div.active').attr('id')
```

This will accurately get the specific ID assuming you only have one div on the page with an **active** class. If you have multiple you may need to perform some kind of loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use basic functions to get the id of an element.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('active')[0].id
```